# Would someone mid explaining what the "TT" bit is in this Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I actually have two simple questions, I hope.

What is the TT used for in this JQuery call below? I cannot find a reference to it anywhere.

```
TTjquery(window).load(function()
```

Also, what does the below relate to/mean:

```
//<![CDATA[ ... //]]>
```

[Where it is usually wrapped around Javascript]

Thats it really, I just want to understand what it is before going forward to make sure I am using the correct calls.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: TTjquery is just a variable name, and it could be anything. Perhaps the code is wrapping jquery in a different object? `TTjquery = $` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TTjquery` has already been explained, so I'll answer your other question.

`<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`, in future referred to as 'the CDATA tag', is a construct in XML and XHTML that includes the contained text as #CDATA where the tag is normally #PCDATA, such as `script`, to avoid issues with characters like `<` and `&`, which are parsed.

In HTML, however, there is no place for the CDATA tag, as not only is `script` already a #CDATA tag, there is also no CDATA tag.

The author who used

```
//<![CDATA[
...
//]]>
```

most likely does not understand the purpose and usage of the CDATA tag, and is using it incorrectly in an HTML (or, worse, XHTML sent as `text/html`) context, where it is completely incorrect and ignored by the HTML parser. The author probably found that he or she needs to comment it out in JavaScript, when in fact, where used properly, it won't need to be at all.

Comment: The commented out CDATA pattern is common when using an XHTML DOCTYPE and a mime type of text/html. It allow the JavaScript parser in the browser to read the JS correctly, and also allows an SGML based validator to not complain in the presence of `<` and `&` characters in the JS. This is not necessary in HTML, so I don't think it is worse in XHTML sent as text/html - it's actually quite a reasonable practice for that situation.

Comment: This is true, but I am basing my explanation around the fact that one should not be writing an XHTML page then sending it as text/html, and that doing such is bad practice. A more detailed rationale for this view by Ian Hickson can be found here: http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Comment: I'm familiar with Hixie's opinion on the subject. I wish he'd separated fact from opinion a bit better in that article. While there are definitely problems to be avoided, they can be avoided, and many, many web sites do so successfully. So long as the XHTML 1.0 spec authorises serving the file as text/html, one person's opinion does not make the practice wrong, no matter how clever he is.

Comment: How does it make sense to write a document in one language, and send it in a way such that it would be parsed with a parser for a completely different language? While it's possible to send XHTML as text/html, it shouldn't be default behaviour; I feel disappointed whenever I look at all those XHTML sites on the web, and not one of them is sent to me as application/xhtml+xml, when my browser can handle it just fine. This is one area where I believe the W3C made a poor decision, and it has been reflected in widespread practice.

Comment: Well, start with my site - http://www.nfstimpson.co.uk/empress . Assuming your browser supports `application/xhtml+xml`, and says so in the accept header, that's what you'll get served. If you use an old IE, you'll get the same pages served as `text/html`. I think that validated XHTML however served comes into its own on very large sites with many developers working on it. It enables the enforcement of rules that allow one developer to be able to visualise the DOM that would be created from the mark-up written by another developer much more easily than is the case with HTML.

Comment: I'm glad that you do. You're a rarity, if you didn't know - last year, I took my own survey of a few hundred of the most popular websites, and of those that served XHTML (most of them), not a single one served it as application/xhtml+xml, even though my request headers explicitly allowed it.

Answer (score 1):

The first is probably a jquery plugin and the second is to protect the content of the wrapper from being part of the DOM and have a 8-bit charset. But I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 1):

TT is for TrueThemes: http://support.truethemes.net/home

CDATA explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: Although your link about CDATA is correct in this situation, please refrain from using w3schools.com as a resource, as it is, more often than not, blatantly incorrect. Please see http://w3fools.com for more information.